# Hbase remove DeleteFamily cells or restore data marked for deletion

Tags: hbase, restore

I have rows deleted by mistake in hbase so now for every such row there is a cell with `type=DeleteFamily`. I've set `KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'TRUE'` so the data is still there, but I need to restore it. As far as I understand scanning the data and then making a put with all the cells except DeleteFamily one won't help because the data is already here. For now I've copied the data to another table with this code:

```
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);


    Table myTable = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("my_table"));
    Table myTableBu = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("my_table_bu"));

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setRaw(true);
    scan.setTimeRange(1490004800000L, 1491004910000L);

    ResultScanner scanner = myTable.getScanner(scan);

    Result result;
    do {
        result = scanner.next();
        if (result != null) {
            Put put = new Put(result.getRow());
            Arrays.stream(result.rawCells()).forEach(it -> {
                try {
                    if (!CellUtil.isDelete(it)) {
                        put.add(it);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Error adding Cell to Put: " + it);
                }
            });
            myTableBu.put(put);
        }
    } while (result != null);
    myTable.close();
    myTableBu.close();
```

Now I am wondering if I can set `KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE'` wait for major compaction and after that copy all the data back or DeleteFamily cells wont be removed after major compaction and copying the data back will return me to the point where I am now. I googled it and found that DeleteFamily cells might not be purged after major compaction.

I'd be glad to here other possible solutions for restoring such data, like maybe there is a way to remove DeleteFamily cells? The only solution I found in Google is copy the data back.

Hbase version is 1.2.0-cdh5.9.0.

Thank you!